# Smart indexing using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

So, this is more like a structural problem but I think it's looking fairy ugly at the moment, I have code looking like:

```
for i in range(length_of_tree):
    potential_ways = np.zeros((M, 2))
    for m in range(omega):
        for s in range(Z):
            potential_ways[m][s] = sum([quad[r][m][s] for r in range(reps)])
```

The code is currently working, but I've noticed that there are several ways using numpy to avoid for-loops, my question is therefore, is there a way for me to make this code a bit more minimalistic?

Comment: Please add quad, omega and reps

Comment: probably. Could you briefly describe what your code does and add in the missing variable samples  with expected output so it can be run and tested?

Comment: I use the code to calculate probabilties, unfortunately, I can't add the variables here and I was sceptical to whether I should post the question without them, I'm sorry that I cant post them, was mostly looking for something general that I could experiment with myself.

Comment: Add some random matrices with the same shape

Comment: potential_ways is a 2x2 matrix, omega = 2, Z = 2, quad is a 100x2x2 matrix, length_of_tree = 100

Comment: I was thinking that maybe I could use [:] instead of my sum in the s-for loop, then i thought, maybe there is a way in numpy to prioritze, lets say I have quad, so that I can write quad[100][:][:] and it would prioritize the "inner" loop first

Comment: Becareful when index arrays with `arr[i][j][k]`.  Usually it's better to use `arr[i,j,k]`.  that's especially true when using slices, e.g. `quad[:][j]` is not the same as `quad[:,j]`.  By itself a `[:]` does nothing; it's not even a place holder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sum over values in an array can always be changed into an inner product which is optimised in numpy. As has been suggested here, I don't really understand the context of your question without examples but you should be able to do something like the following:

```
np.random.seed(1)

# your examples
M = 2
length_of_tree,reps = 100,100
omega,Z = 2,2
# a random matrix of values of shape 100,2,2
quad = np.random.normal(0,1,size=(100,2,2))

# useful initializations
quadT = quad.T
dummy = np.ones(shape=(100,))

for i in range(length_of_tree):

    # option 1
    potential_ways = np.zeros((M, 2))
    for m in range(omega):
        for s in range(Z):
            potential_ways[m][s] = sum([quad[r][m][s] for r in range(reps)])

    # option 2
    potential_ways = quadT.dot(dummy).T
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I'll try to make something similiar like this to my solution!